# Kendo UI Grid's datasource destroy function not called

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have grid with data source, transport is set like

```
        transport: {
            destroy: {
                url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/products/destroy",
                dataType: "jsonp" // "jsonp" is required for cross-domain requests; use "json" for same-domain requests
            },
            //destroy : function(options) {
            //    alert("2342");
            //    options.success();
            //},
            read: {
                cache: false,
                type: "GET",
                url: "/founders/read",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { parentEntityId: parentId },
            },
        },
        batch: false,
        schema: {
            data: "Data",
            model: {
                id: "Id",
                fields: {
                    DateFrom: { type: "date" },
                    DateTo: { type: "date" },
                }
            },
            total: "Total"
        },
```

It works fine, but when i try to use function (commented lines) - it wasn't not called, but i have GET request to my page adress. Why? I checked id value of model - it's correct.

Comment: From first glance, the GET you are getting is probably your "read". It's just getting a new set of data after your destroy is "successful" (options.success();). Also, I'm confused. Is your destroy function called or not? You are contradicting yourself.

Comment: i have GET query to adress of whole page, not to "/founders/read" mentioned at "read" section,  and i see no alerts.

Comment: You should reproduce your situation here and give us the link http://dojo.telerik.com/

Comment: As far as I remember you cannot mix in transport functions with objects. I.e. You cannot have a function for destroy and a url for read. Is this your case?

Comment: @Pluc I have 2 variants of destroy section: as an object  and as a function. As object it works fine, as function - not. Destroy section as function is commented in question

Comment: @OnaBai yes, it is - is it mentioned in documentation somewhere?

Comment: I cannot find it in current documentation version. I remember seeing it in previous releases. Maybe they changed it. Try defining read as a function (return any valid data, just for test) if then `destroy` starts working then is that the limitation is still there.

Comment: @OnaBai thank you! I checked - it was the point, there should be still no mixing at transport section.

Comment: @Horosho I understood that. Please use the link I provided to put up a sample of your code that I can look at.

Comment: @Pluc thank you for helping! we've solved the issue

Comment: @OnaBai can you post an answer, so a can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot mix in a `transport` definition functions with objects. I.e. You cannot have a function for `destroy` and a url for `read`.